# How to Format Bulleted Lists with Long FormText for Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, formatting, html-lists

I've been running into a bunch of formatting issues for bulleted lists with long form content within Wordpress.

Here is an example of my code:

```
<ol>
<li><strong>Example Header 1</strong>
<p>Example paragraph 1.</p>
<p>Example paragraph 2</p>
<p>Example paragraph 3:</p>
<ul>
<li><strong>Example Subheader 1</strong><br />
Example bullet text 1</li>
<li><strong>Example Subheader 2</strong><br />
Example bullet text 2</li>
<li><strong>Example Subheader 3</strong><br />
Example bullet text 3.</li>
</ul>
</li>
<p>Example paragraph at the end of the list</p>
<li><strong>Example Header 2</strong>
<p>Example paragraph 4</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

The most common issues I'm seeing:

1. Wordpress (both Gutenberg and classic editor) are stripping the p tags around example paragraph 1 and 4 and then adding an empty p tag with no text inside after that content. It will then leave p tags around example paragraph 2 and 3 the same.
2. My embedded unordered list will be treated as an embedded ordered list
3. The ordered list will start again at #1 for Example Header 2, when I'd like for that to be list item #2.

My high-level goals are I want the content to all be aligned consistently underneath their headers and subheadings, to have consistent and standard line break sizes, and to have the line items in the ordered lists have correct numbering.

How should I structure my code (or Wordpress) to fix the issues I'm seeing and achieve the goals I'd like.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like this:

```html
<ol>
  <li><strong>Example Header 1</strong>
    <p>Example paragraph 1.</p>
    <p>Example paragraph 2</p>
    <p>Example paragraph 3:</p>
    <ul>
      <li><strong>Example Subheader 1</strong><br /> Example bullet text 1</li>
      <li><strong>Example Subheader 2</strong><br /> Example bullet text 2</li>
      <li><strong>Example Subheader 3</strong><br /> Example bullet text 3.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ol>
  <p>Example paragraph at the end of the list</p>
  <li><strong>Example Header 2</strong>
    <p>Example paragraph 4</p>
  </li>
```

Comment: With that code, Wordpress would strip the p tags around example one and then add an empty p tag after that line. I don’t know why it’s doing that. Is there an issue with the code that’s causing it that I would need to change?

Comment: where are you using the code in wordpress? 
in post or page? or in sidebar or somewhere in your theme (custom page / content)?